# tikz: \coordinate as argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I can define and use a `\newcommand` `\Ball`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Ball}[2]{
  \draw(#1, #2) circle(2 cm);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Ball{1}{4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is a nice Ball:

[image]

But it would be even nicer if I could pass `\coordinate` as an argument to `\Ball`:

```
\coordinate(O) at (1, 4);
\Ball -> pass (O) as argument;
```

in a similar way as I can write:

```
\coordinate(O) at (1, 4);
\draw(O) circle(2 cm);
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the coordinate as a normal argument.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Ball}[1]{
  \draw(#1) circle(2cm);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (1, 4);
  \Ball{O};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would I now run `\Ball` if the arguments are separate x, y? Attempts such as `\Ball{(1, 2)}` fail.

Comment: @Viesturs remove the `() ` from the argument, `{1,2}` should work just fine.